# how long does noip ddns takes to make the updated address again accessible?

Tags: ddns

Yesterday I've created a noip account, I've downloaded the updater client (DUC), I've configured them, and when I've tryied to browse "myaddress.noip.me" all worked fine...

When my WAN IP changes, the DUC client quickly updates it in few minutes, and in my account on noip.com I can see that it is also refreshed properly.

But the problem is that if I try to browse "myaddress.noip.me" after that update, the page does not load... "Unable to connect to myaddress.noip.me"

After 6-7 hours it becomes again accessible, but I'm not sure if this is normal... I think this is too much time...

Please help

Comment: Try to access the the service you want to use via IP address. If this works right after ip address change there is some problem with DNS or the DDNS service itself. As well you may try to ping myadress.noip.me to check if you computer resolves the address to the right IP.

Comment: Yes I can properly access by inserting my IP... However this is strange, because al lot of people told me about noip....

Comment: Its not only about noip. If you access the site with myaddress.noip.me your computer may store the ip 12.12.12.23 for this address. If your ip changes and you try to access myaddress.noip.me again your computer may uses a local cache and try to contact 12.12.12.13 again and not the new address. Thats why you should try a ping it will resolve the address and show you to wich ip you try to connect when you enter the url.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a cache issue, the address is cached both by Windows and by your browser.

After your IP updates you can clear the Windows DNS resolver cache with ipconfig /flushdns

You can clear your browser cache by following the instructions in the following article from Dyn.com who run a no-ip type service.
https://support.opendns.com/entries/26336865-Clearing-the-DNS-Cache-on-Computers-Servers-and-Web-Browsers